# How to queue up multiple material items into a station

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to figure out how to queue 3 material items which would then enter 3 different stations. Lets say the material items are named as (1,2,3). For the first station, it will accept 1 and then 2 and then 3. For the next station, it will accept 2 and then 3 and then 1. And for the final station, it will accept 3 first, and then 1 and finally 2.

So there will be a starting conveyor in which all three material items would be randomly generated, and the conveyor will branch out into 3 other conveyors containing the stations.

I am quite new to anylogic so any help would be much appreciated

New edit:

So what i am trying to accomplish here as you can see there are three conveyors which would converge to one final conveyor where the station is located. There are 3 sources, whereby source 1 would have MyAgent1 , source 2 have MyAgent2 and source 3 with MyAgent3. Before the material items ( MyAgent1, MyAgent2 and MyAgent3) arrives at the final conveyor, I want it to enter based on a specified order - ( MyAgent2 followed by MyAgent1 and finally MyAgent3). Each Myagent will enter individually and not in a group, and the process will repeat itself again.

I tried to utilize the queue block with agent.priority thinking that it will prioritize according to my preference but to no effect.
Im sorry for the lack of anylogic lingo as i am not that familiar with it, if there is any help it would be much appreciated and you may ask for more details. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6EOS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW4Ix.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n21J.png)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you would need a custom station (or many) in which the items wait and are resorted to their destinations.

But beyond saying that I don't think it is possible to give you more details with this level of information

Comment: Hello @Felipe , i have edited my previous post. Would you be so kind as to check on it and ask for anymore relevant details that you might need?