# Queuing up materials based on their configuration

Tags: anylogic

this is a follow up question regarding my previous question

"I am trying to figure out how to queue 3 material items which would then enter 3 different stations. Lets say the material items are named as (1,2,3). For the first station, it will accept 1 and then 2 and then 3. For the next station, it will accept 2 and then 3 and then 1. And for the final station, it will accept 3 first, and then 1 and finally 2.

So there will be a starting conveyor in which all three material items would be randomly generated, and the conveyor will branch out into 3 other conveyors containing the stations.

I am quite new to anylogic so any help would be much appreciated"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIxTb.jpg)

The following are the images of my main page and the blocks involved. I am not familiar with java coding, and i am still racking my brain trying to figure out how to accomplish it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sSJO.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? Please learn how to ask great questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to queue up multiple material items into a station](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67904655/how-to-queue-up-multiple-material-items-into-a-station)

Comment: This is just clarifying your original question and so should have been an edit to the original question instead. I'll propose to close this as a duplicate.